# R preserve zero length groups in frequency table

Tags: r, aggregate, grouping

I have the following dataset:

```
gender<-c('male' ,'male', 'male', 'male','male',
          'female', 'female', 'female','female', 'female' ,'female', 'female', 'female','female')   
clothes<-c('hat', 'hat', 'hat', 'shirt', 'shirt', 'hat', 'hat', 'hat', 'shirt', 'shirt', 'shirt', 'dress', 'dress', 'dress')
color<-c('blue', 'blue', 'green', 'blue', 'brown', 'green', 'brown', 'brown', 'blue', 'green', 'green', 'blue', 'green', 'green')
x<-data.frame(gender, clothes, color)
```

I need to do a frequency table of gender by clothes by color, with NAs for missing colors only. Both genders and all clothes levels should be associated with 3 color levels. However, for one gender level I 'm missing clothes level 'dress', and I don't want it to be populated with NAs, I want it omitted altogether.

I tried tallying:

```
x$color<-as.factor(x$color)
x_agg<-x%>%
  group_by(gender, clothes, color)%>%
  tally()
```

And that does not achieve the purpose at all; I get no NAs for missing levels of any variables.

When I apply the following code:

```
library(tidyverse)
x_agg<-x%>%
  group_by(gender, clothes, color)%>%
  summarise(cnt=n())%>%
  ungroup() %>%
  complete(gender, clothes, color,
           fill = list(N = 0))
```

I get NAs for male - dress - all colors. But what I want is NAs only for the last grouping variable (color), not for both clothes and colors. Like this:

```
gender<-c('male' ,'male', 'male', 'male','male','male',
      'female', 'female', 'female','female', 'female' ,'female', 'female', 'female','female')   
clothes<-c('hat', 'hat', 'hat', 'shirt', 'shirt', 'shirt', 
       'hat', 'hat', 'hat', 'shirt', 'shirt', 'shirt', 'dress', 'dress', 'dress')
color<-c('blue', 'green', 'brown', 
     'blue', 'green', 'brown',
     'blue', 'green', 'brown',
     'blue', 'green', 'brown',
     'blue', 'green', 'brown')
cnt<-c(2, 1, NA, 1, NA, 1, NA, 1, 2, 1, 2, NA, 1, 2, NA)     
x_agg1<-data.frame(gender, clothes, color, cnt)
```

Or here is a picture:
[image]

I think I tried everything I could think of. There were suggestions on stack overflow but all pertained to either grouping by just one variable, or filling in NAs for all levels of every single grouping variable. But it is not clear what to do if only one variable's levels need to be filled in/ retained? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `group_by/summarise`, we can also do `count`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
x %>%
     count(gender, clothes, color) %>%
     group_by(gender, clothes) %>%
     complete(color)
# A tibble: 15 x 4
# Groups:   gender, clothes [6]
#   gender clothes color     n
#   <fct>  <fct>   <fct> <int>
# 1 female dress   blue      1
# 2 female dress   brown    NA
# 3 female dress   green     2
# 4 female hat     blue     NA
# 5 female hat     brown     2
# 6 female hat     green     1
# 7 female shirt   blue      1
# 8 female shirt   brown    NA
# 9 female shirt   green     2
#10 male   hat     blue      2
#11 male   hat     brown    NA
#12 male   hat     green     1
#13 male   shirt   blue      1
#14 male   shirt   brown     1
#15 male   shirt   green    NA
```

Comment: @tadat Please check the upddate

Comment: Super! I accepted the answer and it says the accept should show up in 2 minutes. A small follow up: if I wanted to fill in with 0's instead of NAs, how would I do that?

Comment: @tadat Just use `complete(color, fill = list(n = 0))`